# unsual Font style in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, anaconda

I am making text editor in which i can change font style also, for that i am using font from tkinter but it does not showing usual fonts like "arial". following is the sample code
pls let me know where i did wrong

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
root = Tk()
print(font.families())
```

output---------
('fangsong ti', 'fixed', 'clearlyu alternate glyphs', 'courier 10 pitch', 'open look glyph', 'bitstream charter', 'song ti', 'open look cursor', 'newspaper', 'clearlyu ligature', 'mincho', 'clearlyu devangari extra', 'clearlyu pua', 'clearlyu', 'clean', 'nil', 'clearlyu arabic', 'clearlyu devanagari', 'gothic', 'clearlyu arabic extra')

Comment: Fonts are system specific.

Comment: It looks like it has not been installed on your computer as I can find a lot of fontfamilies in the outputs with your code snippets.